# Prevent node overlap in d3js network map (v4)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is there a way to prevent network graph nodes from overlapping in d3.js v4?

I've tried to use various values for the force `charge` and `d3.forceManyBody()` with and without the `distanceMax()` but they all still overlap. Reducing the radius down to 8 gives more room, obviously, but I need the nodes large enough to label.

This is the d3 block:

https://bl.ocks.org/Ognami/9dd4111eb793eec1645e9cdc7d4ba5b0

Id like for the links to expand out as much as needed so the nodes don't overlap each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a [`d3.forceCollide`](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#forceCollide) to the simulation to prevent overlapping. Increasing `iterations` should make it a little less jittery. Also by adding [`distance`](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#link_distance) to `forceLink()`, you can set a desired link distance, and also using [`manyBody.strength()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#manyBody_strength) you can create a stronger repelling between nodes.

```
        let simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
                .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }).distance(200))
                .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().distanceMax(height/2).strength(-400))
                .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(radius).iterations(10))
                .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width/2, height/2));
```

Comment: That gets rid of the overlap, nice! Though the nodes now cluster tightly around the center. Is there a property I can give that will push all the connections away from the central node? I am able to achieve this by forcing a distance of 200, but don't know if there's a better way?

Comment: You can also increase the links distance by using the `distance` setter for the `forceLink`, and/or using a more negative strength for `forceManyBody`. I've updated my answer to show how to use it